# Were all of Jesus' healings performed on the Sabbath?

Tags: life-of-jesus, exegesis, gospels, sabbath, healing

I was just reading in John 5:1-17 about Jesus healing the man at the pool in Jerusalem, and noticed that this happened on the Sabbath. That reminded me of Him healing the man with the withered hand on the Sabbath. So now I am wondering: were all of Jesus' healings performed on the Sabbath?

If the answer is no, please provide proof. I am especially interested in evidence from Scripture that marks a healing miracle as being performed by Jesus on a day other than the Sabbath.

---

Here are some instances where Jesus healed on the Sabbath: Matt. 12:9-14 // Mark 3:1-6 // Luke 6:6-11; Luke 13:10-17, 14:1-6; John 5:1-18, 9:1-34

Comment: I just wish, for one doggone time, to read "Pharisees were pretty cool with this". Nope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any reason to suppose he restricted healings or other miracles to the sabbath. It seems he was much more free with his healings (cf. Mat. 9:35ff) and with his commands about healing (cf. Mat. 10:7f).

But one instance is enough to disprove the hypothesis: Jesus healed the ear of the servant in Luke 22:49f. Then according to 22:66, he was tried the next day (or later that day, depending on how days are reckoned) and then executed, and Luke identifies the following day after that as the Sabbath (23:54). Hence he healed on a day other than the Sabbath. QED